# Blackberry 6: how to detect a long click on track pad?

Tags: blackberry, click, trackpad

how do you detect a long click on a track pad please? I.e. on this thingy:

[image]

I can detect a *short* click with:

```
public boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    // XXX
    return super.navigationClick(status, time); 
}
```

And also I can detect a long click on a *touch screen* with:

```
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent event) {
    if (event.getEvent() == TouchEvent.GESTURE) {
        TouchGesture gesture = event.getGesture();
        if (gesture.getEvent() == TouchGesture.HOVER) {
            // XXX
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.touchEvent(event);
}
```

But I just can't find how to detect the long click on a track pad (I'd like to show a popup menu in that case)...

Thank you!
Alex

Comment: I would play with `trackwheelClick(int status, int time)` and `trackwheelUnclick(int status, int time)` to determine click length. You'll have to set flags here and there (probably in navigationClick() as well) to not fire normal click events prematurely. Beyond that, I don't know of a LONG_CLICK flag or anything.

Comment: Please enter as an answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would play with `trackwheelClick(int status, int time)` and `trackwheelUnclick(int status, int time)` to determine click length. You'll have to set flags here and there (probably in `navigationClick()` as well) to not fire normal click events prematurely. Beyond that, I don't know of a LONG_CLICK flag or anything.

Comment: will you explain the answer ?